# Crystal Report Formula Condition

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report, formula

I am working on project make reports,

I have created report and I need to sum amount field but base on condition

```
NO  -  Name   - Amount  - Currency  
1 -     a         200       USD
2 -     a         100       AF
3 -     a         400       USD
4 -     a         600       AF
5 -     a         300       USD
------------------------------------------
Total Amount 0
```

I want to make formula if all the currency field is same (AF / USD) then SUM Amount field
But if its not Same value the 0;

```
NO  -  Name   - Amount  - Currency  
1 -     a         200       USD
3 -     a         400       USD
5 -     a         300       USD
------------------------------------------
Total Amount 900


NO  -  Name   - Amount  - Currency  
2 -     a         100       AF
4 -     a         600       AF
------------------------------------------
Total Amount 700


NO  -  Name   - Amount  - Currency  
1 -     a         200       USD
2 -     a         100       AF
3 -     a         400       USD
4 -     a         600       AF
5 -     a         300       USD
------------------------------------------
Total Amount 0
```

I want as same result if I search report that is combine both currency total amount should be 0 and if I search by condition that all currency field is same then sum the amount field
Hope you got the problem and looking forward your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you. here you don't need any formula. make it sample like first insert group for currency and insert crystal report default sum function in group section and another sum function use in report footer section.

Comment: Thank you For your Answer, I already Know that, Convert all my Reporting concept as that But if I could do it like that as i mentioned above, it would be very good.
anyway Thank you